# kernel of action.

Tags: group-actions

If $\phi : G \to Perm(G/H)$ where $\phi$ is the group action on $G/H$ by $G$.

$\phi := g(g'H) = (gg')H$

Why is the kernel of $\phi$ equal to $\cap_{x\in G} xHx^{-1}$

I thought the kernel is $\ker \phi = \{g | gx =x \}$ (so ker is a stabilizer).So in our case it is $g(g'H) = g'H$ . So all forms of $g$ are $\{ e_G, g'hg'^{-1} \}$

I don't understand why we have intersection and why is it not $g'$ but $x$

I use notes from http://www.math.unl.edu/~s-wmoore3/notes/groupThry.pdf (page 3/25)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\ker \phi$ = {g | gx =x } = {g | gxH=xH} = {g | $x^{-1}$gx in H }
= {g | g in xH$x^{-1}$ } = {g | g in $\cap_{x\in G} xHx^{-1}$ = $\cap_{x\in G} xHx^{-1}$

Comment: I can barely read this, but okay I kinda get where you are coming from. But why is my stuff wrong?

Comment: it's true  but i just gave you the details

Answer (score 2):

$g(g'H)=g'H$ iff there exists an $h\in H$ such that $gg'=g'h$, i.e., iff $g\in g'Hg'^{-1}$. The condition that this be true for all $g'\in G$ defines the kernel of $\phi.$

Comment: Going to sound like an idiot here, but don't you mean $gg'h = g'h$?

Comment: Actually I meant what I wrote. If gg'H=g'H then in particular gg'e belongs to g'H.

Comment: how do we know $g' \in H$?

Comment: I am not assuming that, but e belongs to H.

Comment: Oh you are basically saying $(gg')H = g'H \iff gg' \in g'H \iff gg' = g'h$ for some $h$. So basically my answer (even though it doesn't look like it) is actually the kernel = $\cap g'Hg'^{-1}$ am I correct?

Comment: Yep, your $x$ is my $g'.$

Comment: I meant my set $(e_G, g'hg'^{-1})$, but yeah this is just a poor way of writing the intersection.